# Oracle.DataAccess still try to access oraops12.dll after uninstall

Tags: odp.net, oracleclient

First I have both 11 and 12 oracle client on my machine. But when i try to use 11g version of oracle.dataacess.dll .

I already remove a 12c register on regedit and stop service and machince.config related.
but the program was throw "Unable to load oraops12.dll..".

Which path that oracle.dataacess find a config for dll?
Why did it still try to load oraops12 not oraops11.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You may still have the 12c version of ODP.NET in the gac along with it's policy DLLs. The policy dlls may be causing ODP.NET 11 to try to load ODP.NET 12.

Comment: How can i delete that policy dll?

Comment: Using the Visual Studio Command prompt, issue a gacutil /u http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I clear oracle.dataaccess related dll in gac but the problem are still remain.

Comment: Did you remove the policy Dlls too?

Comment: Yes, I already remove that. Is it possibly relate to .Net version?

Comment: I'm back to use 12c version instead now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a policy file in your GAC that is using the "bindingRedirect" tag

Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.config

Do a search for the file (I use Agent Ransack) then edit it.

The contents of the file look like this

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89B483F429C47342"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.112.2.0-2.112.9999.9999" newVersion="2.121.1.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

For some reason, if you install Oracle 12, then try and uninstall it (even using gacutil.exe /u), the binding redirect is left in.

On my machine, it was in C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess\2.121.2.0__89b483f429c47342\Policy.2.112.Oracle.DataAccess.config

It is inaccessible via explorer, use agent ransack to track it down, then right click it and open it in an editor.

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue.  Make sure and remove all of the policy folders and oracle.dataaccess folders that start with 2.12 in both c:\windows\assembly and c:\windows\Microsoft.net\assembly.  2.11x means oracle 11.x, and 2.12x means Oracle 12.x.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Windows Server 2012...

I solved all thing only intalling the [C++ Redistributable Package 2010](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999&tduid=(8118f4c3ccd2e4e61012284bcab2340e)(193031)(1846393)(1402X558040Xa156b167445031dcf872d6dde5a7a193)()))