# C# Application - Still looking for Oracle 12c DataAccess.dll even after complete uninstall

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2005

I'm facing this strange problem.

Before this, I had installed Oracle 12c Client in my machine, but my Oracle Database was 11gR2 all the time.

After I have **completely** uninstalled Oracle 12c and Oracle 11gR2 (Followed the instruction from Oracle forum and etc) this strange behavior occur.

Currently my machine has installed:

- Oracle Database 11gR2
- Oracle ODAC 11.2.0.1 64 Bit

However when I build my application, it shows
[image: Error]
What I have tried:

- Remove the Oracle.DataAccess.dll from the project reference and add it back again
- Toggle 32-bit / 64-bit build option

I have tried with 2 projects,

- Web Application - Visual Studio 2005
- Windows Application - Visual Studio 2013

Both behave the same way. So I don't think this has anything to do with Visual Studio / IIS and this is really not a right time to format my machine.

Anyone had this problem before? Thanks.

Ps: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823221/oracle-dataaccess-still-try-to-access-oraops12-dll-after-uninstall

Comment: Registry might still have reference. Try to modify the ‘Oracle Home’ for all instances to point to the correct location.

Comment: @sstan Oh my god you are really my savior!!! I would buy you a dozen of beer! That worked! I'm able to browse my page, however when I build the project it still says "Could not load file or assembly". Anyway to get through this?

Comment: I'm glad that helped.  For your follow-up question, I suggest you open a separate question, and provide as much details as you can.  I'm sure someone will be able to help you.  It seems like your new problem is not as a difficult to resolve.