# c# - probing privatePath is not working

Tags: c#, database, oracle

In app.config i'm using

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="SMSGateway.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="OracleLibs" />
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

to load dll in OracleLibs subfolder but when run program i get an error:

> OracleConnection Error: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'OraOps12.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Anyone have any idea to fix this. Thanks

Comment: I have found the answer in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892492/set-custom-path-to-referenced-dlls?lq=1

`var dllDirectory = @"C:/some/path";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + dllDirectory)`

Answer (score 0):

First, are you referencing the .dll?

Second, does this address your issue? [Oracle.DataAccess still try to access oraops12.dll after uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823221/oracle-dataaccess-still-try-to-access-oraops12-dll-after-uninstall)

Third, does this address your issue? [Unable to load DLL “OraOps10.dll”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683661/unable-to-load-dll-oraops10-dll)

Comment: If I put the dll in the root folder, the program works.
But I want to put in a sub folder, to be more organized.
I don't have oracle client on my machine. In this project i'm using 3rd libs

Comment: @QuangTrườngNguyễn Did you try (in the Solution Explorer) right clicking on "References," selecting "Add reference," clicking "Browse," and then navigating to the .dll in its desired location?

Comment: @Quang Trường Nguyễn, I am trying to achieve the same thing, i.e. organize the dll outside of the root folder, but when I do that the exe cannot find them. I am using a C++ exe calling a .NET COM Interop dll.